# Multiple file upload Yii 2

Tags: php, image, file-upload, yii2, backend

I'm using mysql DB, I've got table "posts" with columns id, title, text, author_id, image at the moment.

I need to provide a possibility to upload several images to one post in my blog. What's the best way of organizing my DB structure in this case and how it's usually done in Yii 2?

At the moment I just have functionality for saving 1 image and keeping it's path in table field.

Should I keep an array in DB or create another relations table?

Comment: Could you please provide more information about what kind of DB you are using.

Comment: @SalmonKiller, not sure what you mean. I'm using mysql DB, I've got table "posts" with columns id, title, text, author_id, image at the moment.

Comment: There are many different types of databases that work differently. Depending on the specifics of that particular database, the DB structure can be different. Now I would recommend that you insert that information about your database into the question, because there it will be more accessible to people who can potentially answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're working with a conventional RDBMS like MySQL:
It seems you're going from a one-to-one, to a zero- or one-to-many relation, in which case i'd recommend creating another table for your files (for example: `image`*), containing a foreign key `image.post_id` to `posts.id`. Added benefit is that you will be able to more neatly store some metadata about the image, instead of creating a load of extra (but perhaps unneeded columns) in the `posts` table.

The cleanest solution (imho) is usually to stay close to the data structure of your DMBS, instead of placing arbitrary data structures inside a text field, no matter what framework or language you use.

This is different when working with no-sql database like for example MongoDB, where depending on the use-case you may want to use an array property `images` on your `posts` document containing image objects.

**yii naming convention for tables is singular instead of plural*

Comment: okay, thanks. How can I do a form with multiple inputs in yii2? I guess I should render 2 forms at one view and add some javascript?

Comment: The docs provide the answer and a great ready-to-use code example for yii2 ActiveForm:  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#uploading-multiple-files. In plain html multiple `<input type="file">` elements would work just fine as well.

Comment: thanks. I was just thinking about the way I can create a form for my Post model and for Image model (related to post's id) at the same time with one submit button and it doesn't seem clear for me at the moment

Comment: Here you go: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-multiple-models.html

Comment: thanks again :) and last question. I guess I need to create new record for each image? For example, if I upload 3 images, I need to add 3 record to database with columns image_id, post_id, path (to file). So I create UploadForm class, then I create it's instance in controller, get array of images in my form and then use logic like "foreach image - new Image to database" in controller? Am I wrong somewhere? :)

Comment: correct! Loop the post and create a new active record model instance for each record (image) you want to `->save();`